# Nodemailer sending two copies

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

so i have a basic transporter setup with nodemailer.

```
let mailer = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  port: 587,
  secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
  auth: {
    user: 'TheUser',
    pass: 'supersecret',
  },
})
```

in node, not in a route or other subcode. I can call

```
mailer.sendMail({ to: 'TheUser@gmail.com', subject: 'test', text: 'Testing a thing' })
```

In TheUser's account i have two copies of the email in the sent box and receive two in the inbox.

I don't know how to make it a more basic test or what to look for to see where the duplicate comes up. I have put it in a function with console.log's to see i the log get duplicated and done everything i can thing of to make it as basic as possible. Any suggestions to figure out why i am getting duplicates?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what roule handler are you using?

Comment: im using express so it handling the route but this is not in a route. I am just executing the mailer function once when the server boots for these tests.

Comment: surprisingly enough @ZainAbedin , i went back to test it through a route and it did not double up the send.

Comment: @Goofballtech
same problem in my case,
any solution?
i am not using any route,
calling the sendEmail function after receiving message in queue

Comment: @sunilkumar In my instance what i ended up finding was that my server instances were running the process in parallel. I have two load sharing instances of the server and each would find the email and send it at the same time. i had to add some logic to limit it to only run on a single instance.